# Ignore binary serialization on a property

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a regular C# POCO.  At the class level, I am decorating the object with `[Serializable()]`.

That said, I am using the Linq `Sum()` on one of the properties and I am receiving an error upon serialization.  If possible, I would like to just simply ignore this property.  However, the `[XmlIgnore()]` is only for Xml Serialization, not Binary.  Any ideas or thoughts?

The code is something like this, where I would like to ignore `ValueTotal`:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{
  public IList<Number> Nums { get; set; }

  public long ValueTotal
  {
    get { return Nums.Sum(x => x.value); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the repeated point in the replies; BinaryFormatter doesn't care about properties in the first place...

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Cheat and use a method

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo
{
  public IList<Number> Nums { get; set; }

  public long GetValueTotal()
  {
    return Nums.Sum(x => x.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 while I sometimes struggle with Properties being equal to state, and state is sometimes calculated, I'm starting to agree more that if you are doing calculations, then you should use a method as it shows the intent that this value is the result of a calculation. The truth is, why would you serialize a value that is calculated, shouldn't you serialize the data that you want, and then just redo the calculation on the other side?

Comment: I agree NerdFury, this does communicate my intentions better.  Thank you.  -Jessy Houle

Comment: How does this solve the problem "receiving an error upon serialization"?
I assumed Number was not serializable an thus serializing the backing field of the Nums property would fail.

Comment: IMO this is just plain wrong. `BinaryFormatter` doesn't look at methods or properties - it only looks at fields. Changing a property to a field should not *in any way* affect how `BinaryFormatter` works here.

Comment: @NerdFury Sometimes you want some kind of calculated data available for display in data binding. In this case, a method is no good.

Comment: @Benny Jobigan: I agree, but should a class which displays values really need to be serialized? I think the data (model) should be serialized and not its presentation

Comment: @Scoregraphic: eh, maybe, but it's a pain writing viewmodel wrapper classes for every data object I might have. Sometimes it's easier just to bind directly to the object.

Answer (score 62):

`ValueTotal` is already ignored. Only data is serialized, not methods. Properties are methods actually.

If you wish to ignore fields and not serialize them mark them as `[NonSerialized]`.

'Or'

you can implement `ISerializable` and not serialize those field.

Here is some sample code on how can implement `ISerializable` and serialize data: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/102162008172741PM/1.aspx

Comment: If it is an event like `PropertyChangedEventHandler`, it should be marked with _[field: NonSerialized]_. I think this will be useful to people looking at Your answer in search for what I was searching for.

Comment: what were you searching for?`

Comment: I wanted to skip serialization of an event during binary serialization, and the first post I opened was this one. I actually needed the _[field: NonSerialized]_ mark, so I thought it would be useful to comment.

Answer (score 37):

```
    [NonSerialized]
    private IList<Number> nums;
    public IList<Number> Nums { get {return nums;} set { nums = value; }  }
```

Comment: Read again. He likes to ignore the ValueTotal-Property, not the list

Comment: No need to ignore ValueTotal property. Binary serialization serializes fields, not properties

Answer (score 3):

There is another way that is not listed here that has some benefits(the code below was made to support both binary serialization and xml)(for your example you would need a custom class to serialize your interfaces):

```
    [OnSerializing]
    private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        xmlShape4Port = new xmlStreamShape(shape4Port);
        shape4Port = null;
    }
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (xmlShape4Port != null)
        {
            shape4Port = xmlShape4Port.getShapeFromSaved();
            xmlShape4Port = null;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public virtual StreamShape shape4Port {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("shape4Port")]
    public xmlStreamShape xmlShape4Port
    {
        get
        {
            if (shape4Port == null)
                return null;
            else
            {
                return new xmlStreamShape(shape4Port);
            }
        }
        set
        {
            shape4Port = value.getShapeFromSaved();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [**`ISerializable`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface and then use *`[XmlIgnore]`* for XML serialzation in the *GetObjectData()* method but then output as binary. It's actually simpler than how I just described it.

For ideas, see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/102162008172741PM/1.aspx